# How to Resize height and width of a image dynamically in SSRS Report?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I want to resize image height and width dynamically in SSRS report based on expression but there is no expression option available in image size properties its only take numeric values.
I want resize my image like below c# code.

```cs
private void GetImageSize(string path)
{
    try
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
        if (image != null)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image imageResized = ((System.Drawing.Image)image.Clone());
            int resizeWidth = 0;
            int resizeHeight = 0;
            bool heightIsLongerDimension = (imageResized.Height > imageResized.Width);
            float heightInches = (float)(imageResized.Height / imageResized.VerticalResolution);
            float widthInches = (float)(imageResized.Width / imageResized.HorizontalResolution);

            if (heightIsLongerDimension)
            {
                resizeHeight = (int)(imageResized.VerticalResolution * 3);
                //resizeWidth = Convert.ToInt32((((heightInches - 3) / heightInches) * widthInches) * imageResized.HorizontalResolution);
                resizeWidth = Convert.ToInt32((((float)imageResized.Width) / (float)imageResized.Height) * imageResized.HorizontalResolution) * 3;
            }
            else
            {
                resizeWidth = (int)(imageResized.HorizontalResolution * 3);
                //resizeHeight = Convert.ToInt32((((widthInches - 3) / widthInches) * heightInches) * imageResized.VerticalResolution);
                resizeHeight = Convert.ToInt32((((float)imageResized.Height) / (float)imageResized.Width) * imageResized.VerticalResolution) * 3;
            }
            //image height and width set in pixel
            Image1.Height = resizeHeight;
            Image1.Width = resizeWidth;
            //image height and width set in inches
            float width = (float)(Math.Round((resizeWidth / imageResized.HorizontalResolution), 1));
            float height = (float)(Math.Round((resizeHeight / imageResized.VerticalResolution), 1));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hit F4 when you have the image selecyed and find the width and height values in the properties pane. You *should* be able to set an expression from there.

Comment: It takes only static float value .Expression can't be set here.

Comment: Refer above code i want like this.

Comment: Is this possible to change size dynamically using VB script or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom code in your report to define following vb.net function:

```
Public Function ResizeImage(ByVal picbytes as Byte()) As  Byte()
    Try

       Dim ms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
       Dim rms as System.IO.MemoryStream
       Dim bm as System.Drawing.Bitmap

       ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(picbytes)
       bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

        Dim newWidth As Integer
        Dim newHeight As Integer

            Dim originalWidth As Integer =bm.Width
            Dim originalHeight As Integer = bm.Height
            Dim percentWidth As Single = CSng(1280) / CSng(originalWidth)
            Dim percentHeight As Single = CSng(960) / CSng(originalHeight)
            Dim percent As Single = IIf(percentHeight < percentWidth, percentHeight, percentWidth)
            newWidth = CInt(originalWidth * percent)
            newHeight = CInt(originalHeight * percent)


        Dim newImage As System.Drawing.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        Using graphicsHandle As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        End Using

        Dim ms2 = new  System.IO.MemoryStream()
        newImage.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
        Dim bytes = ms2.ToArray()

        Return bytes

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

reference in report the System.Drawing .NET assembly.

then you can reuse function in your expression like:

```
Code.ResizeImage(Fields!Bild.Value)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you click on image box and right click you will see properties option.
You could click image and then hit F4 properties window will show.
There you have Size option. You will see various option there. By default fit proportionally is automatically selected.
You might want to change that to fit to size.
This will resize your image automatically.
Also below link will help you more in details. Have a look at it.
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/display-image-in-ssrs-report/

Comment: I don’t think so you can achieve what you mentioned in your code.

Comment: Is this possible to change size dynamically using VB script or not?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge.